# How to draw quantum circuit with mathematica?

Tags: physics, computational-geometry, quantum-computing

How to draw quantum circuit as the following one with mathematica? 
[image]
I only find [the quantum package](http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/lgomez/quantum/) which is designed for MMA 7.0 as the author said.
But the version of my Mathematica is 9.0 and when I try that package there is an error as following
[image]

How to get over this problem? Is there any other method or package to draw quantum circuit?

Ps: [the mathematica file including the above error](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1pJ0outt)

Comment: Please provide the input expression (cell expression) that does not work.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks! I update the question. If you cannot download it, please let me know.

Comment: I guess you copied the expression from the notebook. If you type the expression using error using the palettes in the quantum package, then the error is gone.

Comment: see [this](http://i.imgur.com/hBmUQko.gif)

Comment: @xslittlegrass Great observation!  It still doesn't explain why the old expression works in v7 yet is broken in v10.

Comment: @xslittlegrass The input form you illustrate does not produce the `AdjustmentBox["\[CircleTimes]", BoxBaselineShift -> -(3/4)]` part that exists in the original (problem) expression.  What I don't understand is why a definition to handle that case (the original) is load in version 7 but not in version 10.  Perhaps it is overwritten at some point?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I guess I agree with you that it may somehow get overwritten. I only used this package for quantum operator algebra, but knows nothing about the quantum computing part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not yet figured out why different definitions for `MakeBoxes` occur, but it seems that adding this definition in version 10 allows your specific example to parse and evaluate as desired:

```
Needs["Quantum`Computing`"]
Needs["Quantum`Notation`"]
SetComputingAliases[];

MakeExpression[
  TagBox[SuperscriptBox[
    RowBox[{"(", 
      TagBox[Quantum`Computing`Private`a_, zz020TPdat, 
       Quantum`Computing`Private`opts1___], ")"}], 
    RowBox[{AdjustmentBox["\[CircleTimes]", BoxBaselineShift -> -(3/4)], 
      TagBox[Quantum`Computing`Private`n_, zz020TPend, 
       Quantum`Computing`Private`opts2___]}]], zz020TP, 
   Quantum`Computing`Private`opts0___], Quantum`Computing`Private`form_] := 
 MakeExpression[
  RowBox[{"zz020TensorPower", "[", Quantum`Computing`Private`a, ",", 
    Quantum`Computing`Private`n, "]"}], Quantum`Computing`Private`form]
```

If you confirm that this solves your problem *for the specific example* I shall try to figure out why this definition is missing or different when the package is loaded in version 10.  (I copied this from version 7, after loading the package.)

Comment: Yeah! It solves the problems. Thanks so much!

Comment: Will you try to figure out why?

Comment: @Eden I did spend some time on it and I couldn't figure out why.  I don't want to have to read the entire package code to track it down.  I think this is the only definition (for `MakeExpression`) that is missing in v10.  Would you please try using it for a while and see if other problems appear?